# WildFly increase request timeouts

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-10

I would like to increase timeout for following cases:

- When I sometimes **deploy** my app which has for example 80MB, WildFly Management Web Concole shows warning **Request timeout**
- When I sometimes **restart server** (node with host-controller) from the web console, it also shows **Request timeout**
- When I sometimes **disable/enable** my app from Deployments -> Server Groups ... **Request timeout**

I use WildFly version 10.1.0.Final in Domain mode.

I was googling a lot but without any success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be that your application is taking a long time to load, longer than the default deployment time specified in the Wildfly Configuration. You could try updating the blocking-timeout or the deployment-timeout.

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="jboss.as.management.blocking.timeout" value="900"/>
</system-properties>
...
<profile>
    ...
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:2.0">
        <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" 
      scan-interval="5000" deployment-timeout="900" 
      runtime-failure-causes-rollback=
        "${jboss.deployment.scanner.rollback.on.failure:false}"/>
    </subsystem> 
    ...
</profile>
```

ref: https://mirocupak.com/enabling-long-deployments-on-wildfly/

Comment: A very important fact is that deployment scanner you can only use in standalone mode.